# Comparar dos arreglos diferentes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, php5

Como podria coparar dos arreglos uno que solo es

```
array1 = [
   0: Object {
       correo: 'asd@gmail.com'
   }
]
```

pero el  segunto arreglo contiene ese mismo dato y otros mas

```
 array1 = [
       0: Object { 
          Line: "0", Level: "0", associateid: "14960100", correo:'asd@gmail.com', … 
       }
       2: Object { 
          Line: "0", Level: "0", associateid: "14960100", correo:'dddd@gmail.com', … 
       }
       1: Object { 
          Line: "0", Level: "0", associateid: "14960100", correo:'aaaaa@gmail.com', … 
       }
    ]
```

quiera obtener un arreglo donde se compararen los dos pero  que me  devuelva la linea del  dato en el cual coinciden.

```
  array1 = [
           0: Object { 
              Line: "0", Level: "0", associateid: "14960100", correo:'asd@gmail.com', … 
           }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te paso un ejemplo de lo que entiendo que buscas... ¿Es correcto?

```
<?php
$arreglo1 = array("a" => "verde", "rojo", "azul");
$arreglo2 = array("b" => "verde", "amarillo", "rojo");
$array_final = array_intersect($arreglo1, $arreglo2);
print_r($array_final);
?>
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [a] => verde
    [0] => rojo
)
```

En fin, dale un vistazo al `array_intersect`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta la respuesta que esta abajo de  la tuya es lo que me envia y lo que quiero comparar